# Read the files that match pattern under each subfolder

Tags: javascript, node.js, glob

I'm having trouble trying to figure how could i configure a script to read just the files that match this pattern: **xxx.model.js** under each subfolder in this structure:

```
modules
├── index.js //The above script configured to read the x.model.js in each folder
├── users
|   ├── users.model.js
|   ├── users.controller.js
|   └── ...
├── questions
|   ├── questions.model.js
|   ├── questions.controller.js
|   └── ...
└── ...
```

The index.js script is the one that has to read each x.model.js (e.g. users.model.js, questions.model.js...).

I'm asking this because i'm using `sequelize.js` (under Node.js, using Express.js), and i want to break the models folder into files for each module, i'm working with a modular structure. Here's the default script that read all the x.js files inside the folder:

```
'use strict';

var fs        = require('fs');
var path      = require('path');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var basename  = path.basename(module.filename);
var env       = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var config    = require(__dirname + '/../config.json')[env];
var db        = {};

if (config.use_env_variable) {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable]);
} else {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(function(file) {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename);
  })
  .forEach(function(file) {
    if (file.slice(-3) !== '.js') return;
    var model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Someone suggest me to use [glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) but i don't really know how...

Comment: You could put a `if (file.endsWith('.model.js') { // Do something }` check

Comment: Could you make an example?

Comment: Ok. While I have never used Sequelize personally, I think this approach should also work in your case. I'll try to come up with an example. If I understand correctly, the code you're asking for is located in `index.js`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I have never personally used Sequelize, this approach should also work for your case. Here's a sample code to get all the absolute path of the **xxx.model.js** files. You should now be able to process each file to your need.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var directories = fs.readdirSync(__dirname).filter(function (file) {
    return fs.statSync(path.join(__dirname, file)).isDirectory();
});

var model_files = [];
directories.forEach(function (value, index, array) {
    var current_model_files = fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, value)).filter(function (file) {
        return file.endsWith('.model.js');
    }).map(function (file) {
        return path.join(__dirname, value, file);
    });

    model_files = model_files.concat(current_model_files);
});

// Do something with model_files here ...
console.log(model_files);
```